# simple unix shell programming errors about unary operator

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have been having some difficulties recently about unary operator. Here is the code below.

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ ${op:0:1} = "-" ];
then
        echo "debug: option!";
fi
```

I am aware about the space requirement I still don't know the reason it won't compile. This is just a simple vi code after all.

Comment: Post the error, either op is empty or contains special characters. Also this is not vi code.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net is your friend here...

Comment: ./tryCompdir: line 5: [: =: unary operator expected

Comment: Some nits: 1. This is not a `vi` code; it's a shell script or `bash` script. 2. bash scripts don't _compile_, they are interpreted by shell & run directly...

Comment: should I initialized op to $@? From what I have heard it was supposed to check for the first argument. here the errors again: 
./operation: line 4: op: command not found
./operation: line 6: [: =: unary operator expected

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned in the comment, your `op` variable is likely empty.

In order to avoid the `bash` error, use double quote in your `if` statement:

```
if [ "${op:0:1}" = "-" ];
then
        echo "debug: option!";
fi
```